# Calculations from CPU to GPU in R?

Tags: r, gpu

I have a question. How can I calculate my little code, for example with kNN on GPU in R? Is it possible? Any idea?

```
library(mlbench)
library(class)
set.seed(2)

data_set1 <- mlbench.threenorm(40000,d=10)
plot(data_set1)

data_set1<-data.frame(data_set1)
index1<-sample(2,nrow(data_set1),replace = TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))
train1<-data_set1[index1==1,]
test1<-data_set1[index1==2,]
nn1<-knn(train1,test1,train1[,11],k=1,prob=TRUE)

mean(nn1==test1[,11])
hist(data_set1$x.10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CUDA capable card, you could try [kmcudaR](https://cran.r-project.org/package=kmcudaR) for knn. There are also other packages available for GPGPU, c.f. the GPU section in the [HPC view](https://cran.r-project.org/view=HighPerformanceComputing). One package that is not (yet) mentioned there is [RcppArrayFire](http://www.daqana.org/rcpparrayfire/), which I am working on. Upstream's [knn example](http://arrayfire.org/docs/machine_learning_2knn_8cpp-example.htm) might get you started.